# How to generate a downloadable PDF with iText?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itext, tapestry

How do I make a PDF file downloadable?

I'm have my web application in Tapestry 4.0.2, Spring and hibernate. when the user clicks in a "Save as PDF" link a PDF should be available to be downloaded.

So far I've a working code that generates the PDF file, but the file is saved on my desktop and what I want to do is that when the user clicks on the link the pdf file should be downloadable instead of being stored in the app. I'm using iText library for this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use a StreamResponse to render the binary and ComponentResources.createEventLink(...) to generate a link to the PDF event.

Take a look at my PDFLink component [here](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/pdflinkdemo) which uses [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to render the PDF binary

* EDIT ***
I just read the fine print (ie Tapestry 4.0.2). I'm unfamiliar with Tapestry 4. I'll leave this answer here as some of it may be compatible.